# Add a password to Office documents through C++

Tags: c++, ms-word, ms-office

I am trying to add a password to a Office (lets say Word) document with C++ but got lost.
I read about "Office Automation Using Visual C++" but figured that's not what I'm looking for.
I can't seem to figure out how to do so,
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) is built into Word. It will be far easier to use that instead of using Office Automation from an external C++ program.